# Google Plus Sign in iOS using UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using google+ sign in my app using the Google Plus SDK. When the user taps on the sign in button the user gets redirected to safari. (Standard Process).

However Apple seems to have changed some rules for this. My App was rejected due to this, stating the following

> The app launches mobile Safari to complete signing into Google+ before returning
>   to the app. However, the use should not have to exit the app to use it.
>
> To resolve the issue, it would be appropriate to revise your app to allow the 
>   user to log through the app, to create another authentication method for your
>   app, or to remove this requirement from using your app

Is someone else facing the same issue and has a solution? A work around could be using a UIWebView and use the OAuth Access Token. However this fails to provide me a Single Sign On feature. Also does anyone know how to share an image using the Access Token (Without SDK features).
I have found the   GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch file in the sdk but still no luck with it. Can anyone help me with this class?

Comment: Are you using the method described here? https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in It doesn't seem to suggest that it will open in Safari.

Comment: ya when i set the class of the button to gppsignin it redirects me to safari...u can also check their sample code it works the same way..

Comment: @rameez Did you manage to figure this out in the end?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff nope still struggling with it

Comment: Hi Rameez, does your app force the user to sign in? I know that you can get rejected for preventing access until the user signs in.

Comment: hey daniel the user need to be signed in to use my app but apple is not happy with the safari redirection. Thats what they have mentioned.

Comment: Our app was rejected for the exact same reason :(

Comment: Our update have just been rejected for the same reason. Our app has been including Google+ SSO since the v1 in April 2014, and many updates have been approved since, but this time, they did not like it.

Comment: I used OAuth and the the app has been successfully uploaded on the app store. But had to remove the share via google+ functionality as google doesn't give write permissions via OAuth.

Comment: App rejected for the same reason ... Mar 2015. It redirects to Safari browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google + iPhone API sign in and share without leaving app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app)

Comment: See my answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app/24577040#24577040

Comment: Theres an official Google SDK now that supports web view sign in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26826933/1652402

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Google has released a new [iOS SDK](http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios) that does supports WebView Sign In, among several other updates and features. (Thanks to John Hjelmstad and Co for working on this)

### Original Post

I recommend strongly against using the outdated GTMAuth2Controller. If you really want this feature please add your voice to the official [Google thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900). The more voices we add there the higher the chance that Google will introduce this feature. Currently Apple are rejecting all Apps that force the user to flip flop from Safari to your App for Google+ Sign In. Even though Apple are aware that this is how Googles SDK does this (Nevermind the fact that Facebook does the same but won't get your app rejected).

Its petty and lame but unfortunately all we can do is appeal to Google to add support for this.

Here's what Google had to say about this issue (I also protested the use of their outdated controller)

> Hi all -- at Google, we aim to make our services available to as many
> users and developers as possible. We have heard a very small number of
> reports of problems of this type, but those app developers appear to
> have eventually gotten approval to launch by working through Apple’s
> standard process.
>
> Meantime, we're continuing to work on improved mechanisms for login. I
> do agree with Daniel that direct use of GTMOauth2ViewControllerTouch,
> or the equivalent UIWebView trickery, is not recommended. Oct 16, 2014

Comment: Already posted on the google thread they say there is no guarantee if you will get any response :(

Comment: @rameez I am not sure you read the thread correctly? Several google engineers have been responding?

Comment: need to check as this was a long time ago don't know about any updates. Hope they make changes to the SDK.

Comment: @rameez I know, it doesn't seem like they are in any rush to do anything about it which really sucks but that thread has been picking up traction of late

Comment: Exactly didn't expect this from them, Dropbox on the other hand made immediate changes to their SDK when apps integrating Dropbox faced similar issues.

Comment: @rameez Amen sir, I am really against Googles SDK its incredibly outdated and the architectural patterns behind it seem lacking. Its a real shame they aren't doing much

Comment: Update: we released a new SDK today that does support WebView Sign In, among several other updates and features. It's been a long time in coming, but we're happy to get this launched, and would love your feedback:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios

Comment: Thanks @JohnHjelmstad updated the post:) appreciate the hard work!

Comment: @JohnHjelmstad I have implemented your new SDK however how does the new SDK incorporate with your other library such as "GTL". I am trying to use GTLQueryCalendar however how do I tie that in with the new GIDSignIn that you guys are using?

Answer (score 1):

I tried merging sample apps for Gmail API and GooglePlus to use UIWebView login instead of Safari and it seems to work:

1. create google project BUT when setting up credentials Installed application type choose Other
2. add/enable Google+ API to your google project
3. add/enable Gmail API to google project
4. follow Google+ instructions and add all frameworks and drag ONE BY ONE GoogleOpenSource.framework, GooglePlus.framework and GooglePlus.bundle (you may not need this since we are not using SignInButton, well just in case it is there) in your project
5. add other linker flags -all_load -ObjC, disable ARC
6. DRAG GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib into your project files (from OAuth2)

[image]

my viewcontroller .h file I added 2 buttons to login and retrieve data, textview to display retrieved data, connected them in the builder. ALSO added interface and property for GTMOAuth2Authentication:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIButton *loginBttn;
IBOutlet UIButton *retriveBttn;
IBOutlet UITextView *profileTextView;

GTMOAuth2Authentication *mAuth;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginBttn;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *retriveBttn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *profileTextView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;

-(IBAction)dologin;
-(IBAction)doretrive;

@end
```

my viewcontroller .m file:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"Google OAuth2 For gglplustest";
static NSString *const kClientID = @"your client id";
static NSString *const kClientSecret = @"your client secret";

@interface MyViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize loginBttn,retriveBttn;
@synthesize auth = mAuth;
@synthesize profileTextView;

-(IBAction)doretrive{
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] autorelease];
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    [plusService setAuthorizer:self.auth];//!!!here use our authentication object!!!

    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                } else {
                    // Retrieve the display name and "about me" text
                    [person retain];
                    NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                             @"%@\n%@\n%@", person.displayName,
                                             person.aboutMe,person.emails];
                    [profileTextView setText:description];
                }
            }];
}

- (void)auth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth finishedRefreshWithFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher error:(NSError *)error {
    [self viewController:nil finishedWithAuth:auth error:error];
     if (error != nil) {
     // Refresh failed
         NSLog(@"Authentication Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
         self.auth=nil;
         return;
     }
     self.auth=auth;
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil) {
        // Authentication failed
        NSLog(@"Authentication Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        self.auth=nil;
        return;
    }
    self.auth=auth;
    [viewController release];//no ARC
}

-(IBAction)dologin{
    NSString *scope = kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin;//Google+ scope
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch 
    authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
    clientID:kClientID
    clientSecret:kClientSecret];
    if ([auth refreshToken] == nil) {
        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
        authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] 
        initWithScope:scope 
        clientID:kClientID 
        clientSecret:kClientSecret  
        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
        delegate:self
        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:authController animated:YES];
    }else{
        [auth beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(auth:finishedRefreshWithFetcher:error:)];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

So now, when view is loaded it does not try to login.

Then on a view when I touch loginBttn that will run dologin method (from GmailMail sample) where I setup the scope to GooglePlus: 1st it will check if there is saved info in keychain, if it is, it will proceed without asking you to login. If not, it will do it as for Gmail login in UIWebView directly inside my app.

[image]

here how it looks after login:

[image]

Then I can touch retriveBttn to run retrieve method (e.g. to get Name, About and emails) that uses GooglePlus sample HOWEVER I set Authorizer to the authenticator that I saved after successful login like that: [plusService setAuthorizer:self.auth];

here is the view before and after retrieve is complete:

[image]

[image]

Seems like it is doing what is is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem you can use **Google libs**. It's has a G+ SDK inside and has `GTMAuth2ControllerTouch`, which provides you sign into all Google service. Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout) how to get this library and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout) is an example how to use it. It's very easy. Also you can find some videos on YouTube, which describes how to install this library.

You can use this library with Google+ SDK, but you need to do some work to merge this 2 APIs.

Comment: Can u post the links of the videos. It would be great help.

Comment: The GTMAuth2ControllerTouch does not even support ARC. I have been unable to get it building from Googles own sample code. The only way to get it working is to checkout the existing code and run it directly

Comment: If your project use ARC, just add `-fno-objc-arc` flag to Google's classes in Project->Build Phases->Compiled Sources.

Comment: @vladislav I understand how to get it working, I was just expressing my concern in using a library that is so archaic. It's almost as if it's better to write our own OAuth controller rather than use theirs... If people are still rolling their own memory management systems then that is definitely worrying. Especially with swift around the corner