# Google Plus iPhone API sign in and share without leaving app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus

I have integrated the **Google+ API** in my App for login and sharing posts. Problem with it, is that everything requires you to leave the app and then come back (it uses URL schemes for this). This is not the expected behavior. I would like to know if there is a way to directly open up the login dialog within the my app it self without going to safari.

I really want to avoid going back and forth between safari and my app.

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app) may helps you

Comment: This is by design. You're asking a 3rd party to validate identity, rather than having the user trust your app. Doing that _within_ your app calls the validity of that hands-off transaction into question. Although, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24577040/957950) to the question Anbu linked indicates that Google now allows you to display a web view within your app. See the [Google post](http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios) .

Comment: Please refer to the this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243379/google-plus-sign-in-ios-using-uiwebview). As already mentioned google has added support.

Comment: You have to look how implement using WebView. I already use it in a Project, nut I don't have access the code to show you. In this form you also don't need the Google+ App installed too.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented same thing for my application. I have used [Google's Sign In SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/). it will present Webview controller inside your app and let you login with your account, after that it will dismiss the Webview controller and call a delegate to get info for user.

> Please read and follow the steps from this link,
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

hope it answers the question.