# GPPSignIn open overlay web-view, instead of directing to browser

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, authentication, google-api

**Is there any way to make the GPPSignIn open in internal web-view and don't leave the app? (similar to Facebook login fallback)**

We got rejected from AppStore, cause of

```
"The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging in to Google plus, 
then returns the user to the app. The user should be able log in without opening 
Safari first."
```

Comment: How are you accessing Safari? Are you using a UIWebView?

Comment: No its the default behaviour.doctordoder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, you can override `-openURL:` in your AppDelegate and handle the request inside your own web view. Wether it works or not, you should [report a problem(link at the bottom of the page)](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)