# Not able to get authorization sucess for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am able to login for Google+ inside my iOS application. I am using the **GoogleOAuth** classes for that.

But  the problem is that i can't set scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login** for permission.

If i try to set this scope then, i can't get authorization success.

Otherwise i am getting success if i don't ask permission for this scope.

But for getting the collection info I need the permission for this scope.

Please help me if anybody aware about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

- Get a reference to the GPPSignIn shared instance:

  ```
  GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  ```
- Set the OAuth 2.0 scopes you want to request:

  ```
   [signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
  ```

  Call `[signIn setDelegate:self];`
- Set up delegate method finishedWithAuth:error:.
  Call handleURL on the shared instance from application:openUrl:... in your app delegate.

  ```
  Call [signIn authenticate];
  ```

Reference, please see "Google+ Sign-In for iOS" at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in . Here is sample code to use GPPSignIn:

Comment: Firstly Thanks for replying :)....  Actually i am aware about integrating Google+ using its sdk but Google+_sdk doesn't offer me login dialog inside the application that's why i was trying  Google+Auth Classes.

Comment: Hope this helps you: [Google + iPhone API sign in and share without leaving app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app/24577040#24577040)