# Sharing on Google+ using Google Sign-In for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, google-signin

One of my apps has been rejected due to Google+ iOS SDK using the mobile safari to authenticate the user. I have surfed the web and I have been following the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577040/1351911) to get my app up and running for Google+. I have recently seen the announcement of the Google Sign-In for iOS that resolves the issue of authenticating within the app using the SDK provided webview.

This is where the problem arises, I want the user to be able to share on Google+ but I cannot see the option in the Google Sign-In SDK to share and the latest Google+ SDK is still using the mobile safari to authenticate. I have two questions now:

1. Can I use both SDKs at the same time to authenticate and share and use the authCode?
2. Am I missing something in both of these SDKs to signing in or sharing? Can Google+ give the option to authenticate within app or Google Sign-In helps sharing on Google+?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blog.xamarin.com/keep-users-engaged-with-ios-9s-sfsafariviewcontroller/"];
    // Construct the Google+ share URL
    NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]
                                      initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];
    urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
                                  initWithName:@"url"
                                  value:[shareURL absoluteString]]];
    NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];

if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
    // Open the URL in SFSafariViewController (iOS 9+)
    SFSafariViewController* controller = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]
                                          initWithURL:url];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    // Open the URL in the device's browser
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Not working. Used above code to share url in google+, but not allow me to show POST button, event it showing on android and desktop browser once load same url in browser.